# Previous rows running string value SQL

Tags: mysql

I have an input table and output should show the running value for a given number of records

```
Input table
*************
date           runtime_secconds 
03-Mar-2022     92                  
03-Mar-2022     586                 
02-Mar-2022     106                 
01-Mar-2022     112                 

Expected Output Result
***********************
date            runtime_secconds    running_seconds_value
03-Mar-2022     92                  92,586,106,112
03-Mar-2022     586                 586,106,112
02-Mar-2022     106                 106,112
01-Mar-2022     112                 112
```

Note: I want to give the input number of records as input. if I say 30 records, it has to give results for the most recent 30 days records

Comment: What about your data indicates why each row gets the designated *running_seconds_value* - eg why does the top row get 4 values and the second row only 3 with their *date* being identical?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to order the rows by `date` then `runtime_seconds`, you can use `row_number()` to get the order in which you want the values concatented, then use `group_concat()`:

```
with u as
(select *,
row_number() over(order by date desc, runtime_seconds) rn
from table_name)
select date,
runtime_seconds,
(select group_concat(runtime_seconds)
from u t2
where t2.rn >= t1.rn) as running_seconds_value
from u t1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10018f31d877bb20923e6a2bf27d160f)